# Jquery ajax get data from localhost (json)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http

I started to work on the Website for our FiveM Server today and want to get the data of a `.json` file, which is located on our server, **from** our server. The problem is, that i can't get get access to the local file from our server... Im working on this since hours and can't find a solution for this problem.

**Console Error:**

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://45.91.251.46:30120/dynamic.json' from origin 'http://45.91.251.46' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

**Javascript / JQuery**

```
$(function() {

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
      type : "GET",
      url: "http://45.91.251.46:30120/dynamic.json",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data[0].clients + " " + data[0].sv_maxclients);
      }
    });
  });

});
```

I would appreciate any type of help <3

Comment: You're violating the same-origin policy because the port number in the AJAX call is different from the port in the original page. The server running on port 30120 needs to send CORS headers.

Answer (score 0):

i have had this issue when testing ajax calls alot, and the solution i found easiest when using localhost is to download an exstention called "CORS Everywhere"

You can then tell it to unblock CORS for certain websites, i only use it for localhost.